# How to specify credentials for external nuget feeds in VSTS nuget restore

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using the built in nuget task in VSTS to do a package restore. Our feed is hosted on an internal Artifactory server, and is referenced as a package source in my nuget.config. I'm then using a nuget service endpoint in VSTS to store the credentials to access that feed.

[image: NuGet task screenshot]

But when I run the build I get the following in the build log, and every request to the nuget feed results in a 401 Unauthorized.

```
CredentialProvider.TeamBuild: URI Prefixes:
CredentialProvider.TeamBuild:     https://ukipo.visualstudio.com/
CredentialProvider.TeamBuild:     https://ukipo.pkgs.visualstudio.com/
CredentialProvider.TeamBuild: URI: http://repo1:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repos
CredentialProvider.TeamBuild: Is retry: False
CredentialProvider.TeamBuild: Matched prefix: 
CredentialProvider.TeamBuild: This provider only handles URIs from the build's Team Project Collection

Unauthorized http://repo1:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repos/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Razor',Version='3.2.3') 16ms
WARNING: Unable to find version '3.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor'.
  http://repo1:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repos: The V2 feed at 'http://repo1:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repos/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Razor',Version='3.2.3')' returned an unexpected status code '401 Unauthorized'.
```

Is there anything else I need to configure to get the task to pickup the credentials in the service endpoint? If I just put them as `packageSourceCredentials` in the nuget.config, it all works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the nuget packages feed is located in internal server, you should use the **[private build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)** which can access the URL http://repo1:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repos/Packages.

And there are two options can add the nuget feed credential when you execute NuGet restore task:

#### Option1: Use nuget service endpoint as you used

You can add Nuget endpoint with Basic Authentication. After enter feed URL, username and password, please also verify the connection before save.

[image]

#### Option2: add credential in your `nuget.config` file

In your local repo, you can add credentical to your project level `nuget.config` file as below command:

```
nuget sources add -name "nuget-repos" -source "http://repo1:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repos/Packages" -username "username" -password "password" -ConfigFile path\to\project\.nuget\nuget.config
```

Then your can commit and push (checkin) the change to remote repo, and build without specifying the nuget service endpoint.

**Note:**

- Since the packages seems located in `nuget-repos/Package`, you should use http://repo1:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repos/Packages as feed URL (not http://repo1:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repos).
- Except 401 error message, there also has a warning that shows the package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3 not found. So please also check if the package exist in your feed.

Comment: Thanks, option 1 works. I was using the API key option which failed but basic auth seems to work fine. Note for anyone else trying this - the Verify Connection option will not work if your feed is only accessible internally, but it will still work from an internal agent.

Comment: Using the API key worked for me if I used the following format for the API key <username>:<APIkey>. Appending the username and a colon before the API key did the trick.

Comment: There's no longer the option to **Verify** your connection in ADO using any of the authentication methods.