# Nuget restore returns 401 unauthorized during Jenkins build for packages in Azure DevOps artifacts feed

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, continuous-integration, nuget, azure-artifacts

We have a CI build working in Jenkins. We have a NuGet package feed in Azure DevOps, and we are getting a `401 Unauthorized` error when restoring NuGet packages during a build:

> https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/X/_packaging/FeedName@Release/nuget/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/X/_packaging/FeedName@Release/nuget/v3/index.json.
>       Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Jenkins setup:

- Windows 10
- Jenkins 2.199
- NuGet 5.3.1.6268
- Java 1.8.0_191
- Jenkins is running as a Windows Service logged in a "Local System."

I have the NuGet Credential Provider installed on the Jenkins machine, but I installed it when logged in as myself. I replicated the steps I took on my laptop to get around this same issue. My laptop is working. The Jenkins server is not, and I think it has something to do with the NuGet Credential Provider not working for the "Local System" account, but have no idea how to fix this.

The build is controlled by a PowerShell script, and the NuGet restore command looks like:

```
& "$solutionPath"\.nuget\NuGet.exe restore "$solutionFile"
```

- `$solutionPath` is the folder in which the .sln file exists for Visual Studio
- `$solutionFile` is the exact file name for the .sln file

After reading [How to specify credentials for external nuget feeds in VSTS nuget restore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46794711/3092298) I also added a new "source" to the local NuGet installation via:

```
.\.nuget\NuGet.exe sources add -name "FeedName" -source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/X/_packaging/FeedName@Release/nuget/v3/index.json" -username <my username> -password <my personal access token> -configfile .\.nuget\NuGet.config
```

Usernames that I tried:

- My actual username
- My e-mail
- And just `.`, like the Jenkins config needs to authenticate with Azure DevOps when getting the latest version of our code via TFVC

The `-password` argument was a copy and paste of a Personal Access Token with read/write permissions to the Azure DevOps artifacts feed.

But again, I was remoted into the Jenkins machine as my username when I did this, and I'm still getting the same problem.

**How to fix `401 Unauthorized` when restoring NuGet packages during a Jenkins build when the packages are coming from an Azure DevOps artifacts NuGet feed?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the name of the Personal Access Token (PAT) as the username. That is the name that you gave to the PAT while creating it.

Edit `.nuget/NuGet.config` and add the following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyPackages" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/_packaging/FeedName@Release/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <!-- Tag name 'MyPackages' matches 'key' attribute under packageSources -->
    <MyPackages>
      <!-- Username is the name you gave your Personal Access Token in Azure -->
      <add key="Username" value="NameOfPersonalAccessToken" />

      <!-- Choose one of the tags below: -->

      <!-- Use Password if PAT is encrypted -->
      <add key="Password" value="EncryptedPersonalAccessTokenGoesHere" />

      <!-- Use ClearTextPassword if PAT is unencrypted -->
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="PlainTextPersonalAccessTokenGoesHere" />
    </MyPackages>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I added to your answer. It took me some digging around to get things right. Hopefully the info I added will help others so they spend less time on the solution.

Comment: How do you get the encrypted personal access token?

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: you do that in Azure DevOps. You can search **generate personal access token in Azure DevOps** to find the Microsoft documentation. You need an Azure account.

Comment: Show me where in MS documentation it explains how to get an encrypted PAT or encrypt an existing plain text PAT. I searched and found nothing. Your answer either needs to be improved with supporting documentation on how to do this, or your answer is wrong or misleading. `<add key="Password" value="EncryptedPersonalAccessTokenGoesHere" />` and `<add key="ClearTextPassword" value="PlainTextPersonalAccessTokenGoesHere" />` implies some kind of encryption is available, and I'm not finding any info on them. Maybe you meant `<add key="ClearTextPassword" value="PlainTextPASSWORD" />`? You tell me.

Comment: or searching for, "generate personal access token in Azure DevOps to find the Microsoft documentation" doesn't suffice... I don't know. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

While the OP was unblocked, I had a totally different issue resulting in the same behavior on an Azure DevOps pipeline using a private NuGet feed hosted on ADO.

I was following the [Azure Artifacts Credential Provider guide](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider), and had set the environment variable of `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` as a Secret variable.

After a couple days of hair-pulling debugging, I ran across [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/issues/43#issuecomment-442564517) on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/issues/43) which totally blew my mind. That env-var gets auto-generated, given the right circumstances.

> I should have mentioned this in my first message but the NuGet build task will automatically populate the VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS variable if the Azure Artifacts credential provider (V2) is being used and the "Credentials for feeds outside this account/collection" section is filled

So I followed the rest of the instructions and set these variables up, even though SESSIONTOKENCACHE had already been set.

`NuGet.ForceEnableCredentialProvider=false`

`NuGet_ForceEnableCredentialProviderV2=true`

`NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_MSAL_ENABLED=true`

`NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED=true`

and removed `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` completely.

And that was that. Unblocked, finally.

What was odd was that before I was unblocked, NuGet was working fine for `restore` and `push`, just not `list`... very odd.